Golden Layout v2 Stack size issues
We have migrated from old golden-layout to golden-layout 2 in our Angular 17 app, and things are mostly working as expected, however I have one bizarre issue left that I have not been able to solve.
In our app we have dashboards, which contain a golden-layout with some widgets inside the layout. Each widget is a standard wrapper with a (golden-layout) ContentItem inside it.
The configs for each dashboard are stored on back-end, so whenever a dashboard loads, it gets the config from server and initialises golden-layout with this config.
Part of app functionality is user can customise this dashboard and save it as a custom dashboard for only themselves. Process is like this:

User visits standard dashboard
User customises dashboard in some way - adding/removing widgets, rearranging them, resizing them, etc and then saves dashboard
User is then redirected to new custom dashboard

The issue is that if user resizes the widgets on a dashboard and then saves the dashboard, when user is redirected to the custom dashboard, the sizes of the widgets is ignored. Other changes like adding/removing/rearranging the widgets are preserved, it is only the sizes of the widgets that is ignored. But then if user does a refresh in the browser and custom page loads again, then it does have the correct heights as set by the user before saving custom dashboard.
These are some things I checked:

Correct heights are sent to the back-end when saving the page after resizing - they are.
Correct heights are returned from the back-end when redirecting to the new
portal page - they are.
New heights are passed into the GoldenLayout loadLayout method after returned by back-end - they are
I've tried clearing the layout with goldenLayout.clear() before calling loadLayout - made no difference
I've tried completely destroying the layout with goldenLayout.destroy() before calling loadLayout - made no difference
I've tried explicitly setting the new heights manually on the components inside the stacks - made no difference
I've tried using the new golden-layout-2 size property instead of the old width/height properties - made no difference

Whether page is loaded from scratch or redirected after saving page we still go through same life-cycle, so config is returned from server, new GoldenLayout() and loadLayout are used both times.
I saved the configs that are returned when loading page from scratch and after being redirected and checked them in Kdiff - they are mostly identical except for height properties and some minor differences like having null instead of empty string for row/column titles.
Here is a copy of config returned by back-end when originally loading a dashboard:
{
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "row",
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "column",
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "type": "stack",
                            "content": [
                                {
                                    "type": "component",
                                    "content": null,
                                    "width": null,
                                    "height": null,
                                    "id": null,
                                    "isClosable": true,
                                    "title": "Widget 1",
                                    "componentName": "widget-golden-instance",
                                    "componentState": {},
                                    "widgetLayoutedInstanceId": "1678f085-fd28-403b-b704-3a79eb66ae7a",
                                    "componentType": "widget-golden-instance"
                                }
                            ],
                            "width": null,
                            "height": 27.1869849654493,
                            "id": "c895ec22-ec21-483b-a050-be9c4c30f580",
                            "isClosable": true,
                            "title": "",
                            "componentName": null,
                            "componentState": null,
                            "widgetLayoutedInstanceId": null
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "stack",
                            "content": [
                                {
                                    "type": "component",
                                    "content": null,
                                    "width": null,
                                    "height": null,
                                    "id": null,
                                    "isClosable": true,
                                    "title": "Widget 2",
                                    "componentName": "widget-golden-instance",
                                    "componentState": {},
                                    "widgetLayoutedInstanceId": "a2893d62-8d46-44c7-85f8-2962c51a1f2e",
                                    "componentType": "widget-golden-instance"
                                }
                            ],
                            "width": null,
                            "height": 31.9728276435933,
                            "id": "68c4c539-c387-42f7-ba05-6d8352e6749c",
                            "isClosable": true,
                            "title": "",
                            "componentName": null,
                            "componentState": null,
                            "widgetLayoutedInstanceId": null
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "stack",
                            "content": [
                                {
                                    "type": "component",
                                    "content": null,
                                    "width": null,
                                    "height": null,
                                    "id": null,
                                    "isClosable": true,
                                    "title": "Widget 3",
                                    "componentName": "widget-golden-instance",
                                    "componentState": {},
                                    "widgetLayoutedInstanceId": "65cd9ba3-6ac1-4b30-8a09-d6c7c66eec44",
                                    "componentType": "widget-golden-instance"
                                }
                            ],
                            "width": null,
                            "height": 40.8401873909574,
                            "id": "a296858d-2494-4178-a4d6-09f49dae300f",
                            "isClosable": true,
                            "title": "",
                            "componentName": null,
                            "componentState": null,
                            "widgetLayoutedInstanceId": null
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": 100,
                    "height": null,
                    "id": "388d4498-b157-43b1-bf4d-038bd1d5509f",
                    "isClosable": true,
                    "title": "",
                    "componentName": null,
                    "componentState": null,
                    "widgetLayoutedInstanceId": null
                }
            ],
            "width": 100,
            "height": null,
            "id": "b167d6ca-f57f-4add-bdcf-1cf5323b3558",
            "isClosable": true,
            "title": "",
            "componentName": null,
            "widgetLayoutedInstanceId": null
        }
    ],
    "dimensions": {
        "defaultMinItemHeight": "60px",
        "defaultMinItemWidth": "300px",
        "dragProxyWidth": 300,
        "dragProxyHeight": 300
    },
    "settings": {
        "hasHeaders": true,
        "showPopoutIcon": false
    }
}

And here is copy of config returned by back-end after being redirected (when sizes are of items are not correct):
{
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "row",
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "column",
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "type": "stack",
                            "content": [
                                {
                                    "type": "component",
                                    "content": null,
                                    "width": null,
                                    "height": null,
                                    "id": null,
                                    "isClosable": true,
                                    "title": "Widget 1",
                                    "componentName": "widget-golden-instance",
                                    "componentState": {},
                                    "widgetLayoutedInstanceId": "1678f085-fd28-403b-b704-3a79eb66ae7a",
                                    "componentType": "widget-golden-instance"
                                }
                            ],
                            "width": null,
                            "height": 41.79549901048402,
                            "id": "c895ec22-ec21-483b-a050-be9c4c30f580",
                            "isClosable": true,
                            "title": "",
                            "componentName": null,
                            "componentState": null,
                            "widgetLayoutedInstanceId": null
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "stack",
                            "content": [
                                {
                                    "type": "component",
                                    "content": null,
                                    "width": null,
                                    "height": null,
                                    "id": null,
                                    "isClosable": true,
                                    "title": "Widget 2",
                                    "componentName": "widget-golden-instance",
                                    "componentState": {},
                                    "widgetLayoutedInstanceId": "a2893d62-8d46-44c7-85f8-2962c51a1f2e",
                                    "componentType": "widget-golden-instance"
                                }
                            ],
                            "width": null,
                            "height": 17.36431359855858,
                            "id": "68c4c539-c387-42f7-ba05-6d8352e6749c",
                            "isClosable": true,
                            "title": "",
                            "componentName": null,
                            "componentState": null,
                            "widgetLayoutedInstanceId": null
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "stack",
                            "content": [
                                {
                                    "type": "component",
                                    "content": null,
                                    "width": null,
                                    "height": null,
                                    "id": null,
                                    "isClosable": true,
                                    "title": "Widget 3",
                                    "componentName": "widget-golden-instance",
                                    "componentState": {},
                                    "widgetLayoutedInstanceId": "65cd9ba3-6ac1-4b30-8a09-d6c7c66eec44",
                                    "componentType": "widget-golden-instance"
                                }
                            ],
                            "width": null,
                            "height": 40.8401873909574,
                            "id": "a296858d-2494-4178-a4d6-09f49dae300f",
                            "isClosable": true,
                            "title": "",
                            "componentName": null,
                            "componentState": null,
                            "widgetLayoutedInstanceId": null
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": 100,
                    "height": null,
                    "id": "388d4498-b157-43b1-bf4d-038bd1d5509f",
                    "isClosable": true,
                    "title": "",
                    "componentName": null,
                    "componentState": null,
                    "widgetLayoutedInstanceId": null
                }
            ],
            "width": 100,
            "height": null,
            "id": "b167d6ca-f57f-4add-bdcf-1cf5323b3558",
            "isClosable": true,
            "title": "",
            "componentName": null,
            "widgetLayoutedInstanceId": null
        }
    ],
    "dimensions": {
        "defaultMinItemHeight": "60px",
        "defaultMinItemWidth": "300px",
        "dragProxyWidth": 300,
        "dragProxyHeight": 300
    },
    "settings": {
        "hasHeaders": true,
        "showPopoutIcon": false
    }
}

I've pretty much run out things to check/fix at this point - hoping someone can suggest something I may have missed
